# upload file to my server using pentaho data integration(pdi)

Tags: file-upload, webserver, pentaho, jobs

On my pdi transformations, a file is created and then a table on my database_1 is updated with the information on that file.
That work perfectly fine.

What i need now is to upload the file to some place in my web server. But I want to upload it **automaticaly** each time I finish the transformation described above.

There is any job that could send a file to my web server?! or any other viable automated ways to do it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use the SFTP step?

Comment: yap it works!! thanks!!
I was only checking the steps of a transformation, and completely forgot about the steps on the jobs....